# NetworkManager Replacement

Tags: networking, wireless

Frankly, NM sucks I don't know why GNOME hasn't replaced it. Years ago, I used wicd, but that program seems abandoned.

Any ideas about another GUI for network management? I realize I *could* just use ifup, netplan, and/or systemd's networking piece; but, I'm wondering about a full NM replacement.

Thanks, all...

Comment: Rather than complaining about NM, why don't you tell us what problems you are having with it, and maybe we can help change your mind.

Comment: I've sought help in all appropriate fora and the eventual answer is always the same: that's just nm. So, I wasn't interested in another dissertation about its benefits, just wanted to look at some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Connman](https://01.org/connman) ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/connmanctl.1.html)) and its [Qt GUI](https://github.com/andrew-bibb/cmst/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Intel Inside, just sayin'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'll check it out....